# how does one install Debian on a windows 10 (uefi) computer?

Tags: debian, uefi, debian-installer

The last time I installed Linux (on an x86), I had an old fashioned BIOS, and I would install windows, then Linux (Debian), then grub on the MBR (which would put the windows boot record on the windows partition).

Now, I've got a uefi based computer without a "recovery disk" (all I have is a recovery partition).

What do I have to take into account considering uefi?

For example, do I still need grub (or does uefi take care of boot losing)?

Where should I put it? Is there still such a thing as an MBR?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you'll have to consider is to choose, during the Debian install, the **EFI system partition** and mount it on `/boot/efi`. If there isn't one, create it with fat32 filesystem. 256MB should be OK for it.

You will still need GRUB.

You will have to install it on the drive where the installation will be (if requested), such as `/dev/sda` (like on legacy BIOSes), and it will be stored in the EFI system partition.

Then, to set Debian's GRUB to start automatically, go into the UEFI BIOS settings and set debian to be first (in UEFI you don't choose disks priority, but OSes priority).